# Magento configurable.js - what does separatorIndex do?

Tags: javascript, magento

I would like to know what the following code does as I am having issues with a custom configurable selector + AJAX preview from the category list view.

```
    var separatorIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#');
    if (separatorIndex != -1) {
        var paramsStr = window.location.href.substr(separatorIndex+1);
        var urlValues = paramsStr.toQueryParams();
        if (!this.values) {
            this.values = {};
        }
        for (var i in urlValues) {
            this.values[i] = urlValues[i];
        }
    }
```

The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`

This only happens when I have a hash in the URL (layered nav).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var separatorIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#'); // Looks for index of # in url
if (separatorIndex != -1) { // If # exists and index is set
    var paramsStr = window.location.href.substr(separatorIndex+1); // Get everything after the # in url
    var urlValues = paramsStr.toQueryParams(); // Transform to key value
    if (!this.values) { // Don't know where this comes from?
        this.values = {};
    }
    for (var i in urlValues) {
        this.values[i] = urlValues[i]; // Fill up the this.values with values from the substring after #
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured this is used when you want to send parameters as an anchor to have an option already selected etc, would that be right? Thanks for your prompt answer!